# Asking a question with no shown research

Tags: discussion

I had trouble understanding some concepts while working with a framework and contacted the creator via email. He did a fantastic job explaining the concepts to me and asked in the future to post my questions here and send him the link. I plan on rewriting my question here even though I already have the answer because it may be useful to others.

Since my question has already been answered off-site, would it be wrong for me to ask a question along the lines of:

I'm having trouble understanding the XYZ approach using in ABC framework and need some clarification as to what properties/other items get stored in X vs Y vs Z and how they relate to each other.

The hangup I'm having is that I show no prior research even though I've done so before contacting the creator, but since the question has already been answered and I'm just sending the link over to the creator to answer for himself, I don't want to clutter up the question more than necessary.

So what is the consensus for this type of question: Do I post the minimal question showing no research since it has already been answered and is only being posted here for the benefit of others or do I post a question with additional information showing that I made an attempt to understand the topic beforehand even though it's largely irrelevant now?

Comment: If doing basic research on the topic results in you finding the answer to the question, there's no need to re-post that *already readily accessible information* on SO.  If the information *isn't* already accessible, then make that clear, and you've "shown your research".  All that said, that you know the answer to a question doesn't mean that the question quality standards don't apply when asking a question, because they still do.

Comment: @Servy "All that said, that you know the answer to a question doesn't mean that the question quality standards don't apply when asking a question, because they still do." That's precisely my hangup, but your first portion of your comment is a solid response.

Comment: _"but since the question has already been answered and **I'm just sending the link over to the creator to answer for himself**"_ Not sure, but it sound like it might be interpolated as an innocent vote fraud (Again - Not sure, i'm just pointing it out)

Comment: @AlonEitan How is it voting fraud to send a link to a question for someone to post an answer to?  You're more than welcome to share links to your question.  If you go around telling your friends to upvote your questions, then *that* is voting fraud; giving them a link so they can answer it isn't.

Comment: @Servy That's why I wrote _innocent_ - I was thinking about an hypothetical scenario where one post a question, and then only accept the answer written by a specific user, no matter if it's better/worse than other answers. I'm not sure if it's fine/fair to do that

Comment: @AlonEitan That's not what you, or Tim, described, but even if it *were*, that's *still* not voting fraud.  The accepted answer is for the answer that helped you the most, not some "objectively best" answer.  If that's the answer that the OP used, and that helped them the most, then it's appropriate to accept it, even if someone else posted an answer that other people liked more.

Comment: @Servy i'll take your word for it, I guess that as long as both the question and the answer are up to SO standards then It's fine to do so